# redirect() between views in separate apps

Tags: django

I am following a Django tutorial where the `blog` app and `users` app are separate. Upon registering as a user I would like the user to be redirected to a view in the `blog` app. Here is the `users` app `views.py`:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # if form was submitted w data
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST) #instantiate form w post data
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}')
            return redirect('blog-home') #not working
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```

and here is the `blog` app's `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'posts':posts})
```

and the url pattern tied to said view:

```
path('', views.home, name = 'blog-home'),
```

When a user submits the form, I get the following error: `Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

I am not sure why this is, I believe I copied the code word for word and the example in the video is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app's urls.py mention app_name so that you can redirect to any app's views.

blog/urls.py

```
app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns =[...
]
```

Now you can redirect to the blog app home view like this

```
return redirect ('blog:blog_home')
#return redirect ('app_name:url_name')
```

Comment: I did not realize that I already had this in my blog/urls.py and that the tutorial's code worked as is because they did not. Anyway, good to know that if inlcude app_name I need to reference it in a redirect(). Thanks, this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to url named 'blog-home' you  need to reverse('blog-home').

Your url isn't called 'home' but 'blog-home'. Your error mention that you tried to reverse for 'home'.

It should work if you change your view:

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # if form was submitted w data
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST) #instantiate form w post data
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}')
            return redirect(reverse('blog-home'))
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```